# Build social graph of friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need in my application to build a social graph of friends for each user.
Like it is doing the facebook app "Social Graph":
[App URL](http://apps.facebook.com/126547340780835/).
As I have seen there is no way to extract the friends of friends besides they are also using the application. So what I was thinking about is to extract the friends and for each pair of friends I can check with friends.areFriends whether they are friends and so build the social graph.
But for a user with 300 friends, I need 45.150 API calls. Which exceeds the API call limit per hour.
So is there a way to cast more queries in an API request. Or any suggestions how I can build this social graph in a better way??

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a slightly different approach to doing this.  You should store what you can in your data store for quicker querying.  You should implement the Real-Time API from Facebook and subscribe to each user's friend requests.  This way you can keep track of friendship links to start fleshing out your social graph.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I will look into the Real-time API more in detail. I think it might be very useful in my application. But I think in this way I can handle only the friendships regarding the user (user <-> new friend). I will probably not get relationships notifications about (users' friend <-> users' friend) which I need for the graph. Am I right???

Comment: When the user logs in, you can get their listing of friends.  Store that when they log in.  But don't forget to also implement their deauthorization callback (set the url in the app settings).